Is it possible for a shockwave to reflect off of the ground, making the observer hear 2 shocks?
Is it possible for a shockwave from a supersonic aircraft to reflect off of the ground, forcing the observer to hear 2 shockwaves?

In this picture, the shockwave from this aircraft is shown to reach the ground. When oblique shockwaves contact an obstacle, they will reflect. Depends on the obstacle shape and type. (I don’t know for sure about those statements)
(I think that also depends on the medium the shock is coming into contact with, for example I don’t think a shock would reflect off of a very soft / fuzzy pillow or a sound absorbing material)
After it reflects, it would be heading back into the sky at an angle. Wouldn’t this make the observer hear 2 shocks? (The reflected one and original)

Seems more like a Physics question, rather than Aviation.

@RalphJ It has to do with aerodynamics, which is on topic for this site. But I do see where this wouldn’t really fit in, so if you would like to migrate it I wouldn’t mind.

Why should it be different then echo? So yes.

Rough terrain like that pictured would serve to scatter the reflected shock.  Lets imagine that the observer were on a hard smooth surface first.
Yes, they would hear two shocks -- however they would be so close together that the human ear probably couldn't really differentiate them.  When a supersonic aircraft flies over, the shock system has usually formed itself into an N-wave, which primarily consists of a shock at the front and another at the aft of the aircraft.  So, a sonic boom is often a double-boom already -- with the separation based on the speed of the aircraft and the length of the airplane (i.e. how long the airplane takes to fully pass).
You'll hear the reflection of the front shock well before the aft shock comes.  But again, the human ear may well muddle it all together.
Generally speaking, in acoustics, the ground reflection does tend to double the amplitude of a sound (+3dB).  Consequently, when we make certain kinds of measurements (meant to simulate free-air noise), we actually place the microphone on a hard plate at ground level.  That way, the mic only picks up the sound once.

"n-wave" is a new term for me. If it's new to anyone else, here's a definition from a US Air Force fact sheet.
